# vb.net cboboxes select a value from one and auto select the index number from the other

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, combobox

Hey all i am trying to auto select the email value from a 2nd cbobox when the user selects a name from the first cbobox using the first cbobox's index. (the values all line up with each other just fine)

This is my current code:

```
Private Sub cmbAnalyst_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbAnalyst.SelectedIndexChanged
    theAName = cmbAnalyst.Text
    Dim intSelectedIndex = cmbAnalyst.SelectedIndex

    cboEmails.SelectedValue = intSelectedIndex
End Sub
```

I get the index just fine **(intSelectedIndex)** but i am unable to have it select the email in the second cbobox. Nothing ever selects when i choose a name.

Any help would be great! :o)

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use SelectedIndex on the 2nd combobox too.

```
Private Sub cmbAnalyst_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbAnalyst.SelectedIndexChanged
    theAName = cmbAnalyst.Text
    Dim intSelectedIndex = cmbAnalyst.SelectedIndex

    cboEmails.SelectedIndex = intSelectedIndex
End Sub
```